# Windows 10 issue, right click menu no longer has a "New" option

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

I've already attempted a registry fix for this one, but to no avail, hoping someone can help me with a solution. When I right click on an empty space, it doesn't matter where: desktop/folder/etc, I no longer even have the menu option to create a new file or folder. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: If you create a new user does it exhibit the same behavior

Comment: Testing that, just a few moments please.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this, apparently the "New" key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\
Had been deleted, likely by some rouge 3rd party app.
I simply created a "New" key and set the default value to:
{D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}

Worked like a charm, thanks for the help!

Comment: You mean HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\New.........or did the entire ContextMenuHandlers key get deleted?